# Question for a Limit to Infinity

Tags: limits, improper-integrals

$$\lim_{b\to ∞} \left[\ln b - \frac 1 2 \ln(b^2+1) - \frac 1 2 \arctan(b)\right] $$

Im just confused a bit , I was trying to solve this integral 
https://www.symbolab.com/solver/definite-integral-calculator/%5Cint_%7B2%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7Barctanx%7D%7Bx%5E%7B2%7D%7Ddx

And it says the limit to the given function is $0,$ when i think it should be $-π/4$. Sorry to ask this naive question, but could someone help me out with this ?

Comment: I think you copied the wrong expression for the arctangent. It should be $-\frac{arctan(b)}{b}$

Comment: @aleden : . . . except that it should be $-\frac{\arctan(b)} b$ rather than $-\frac{arctan(b)} b. \vphantom{\dfrac{}{\dispalystyle\int}}  \qquad$ Maybe the difference is more conspicuous with larger type: $- \dfrac{\arctan(b)} b$ versus $-\dfrac{arctan(b)} b \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Pedantic but I agree.

Comment: @A---B : Yes, I know some people think things like this are merely pedantic. That is a weakness that probably can be overcome.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\ln b - \frac 1 2 \ln(b^2+1) = \ln \frac b {\sqrt{b^2+1}} = \ln \frac 1 {\sqrt{1 + \frac 1 {b^2}}} \longrightarrow \ln \frac 1 {\sqrt{1+0}} = \ln 1 = 0 \\[8pt]
\text{as } b\to \infty.
\end{align}

And also
$$
\arctan b \longrightarrow \frac \pi 2.
$$

So you need to recall identities involving logarithms, and properties of trigonometric functions.

And now looking at the integral rather than at the limit you had in your posting, we see that you actually needed
$$
\frac{\arctan b} b \to 0 \text{ as } b \to \infty \quad \text{since } \arctan\to\frac\pi 2.
$$

Comment: Thankyou sir , I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. One may write, as $b \to \infty$,
$$
\arctan b=\frac \pi2- \arctan \frac 1b
$$ and
$$
\frac 1 2 \ln(b^2+1)=\frac 1 2 \ln\left[b^2\cdot \left(1+\frac 1{b^2}\right)\right]=\ln b+\frac 1 2 \ln\left(1+\frac 1{b^2}\right).
$$ Can you take it from here?